Does a successful save against web count as "breaking free"?
The web spell, like many spells that impose the restrained condition, has an initial save to avoid the effect and a subsequent check to overcome the effects of a failed save.
However, the spell also continually asserts itself, requiring a new save each round:

Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that enters them during its turn must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is restrained as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free.

For a creature that is unrestrained and enters the webs or starts its turn there, the save is straightforward - on a successful save it remains unrestrained, but on a failed save it is now restrained by the spell.
However, consider a creature that starts its turns in the web, but already restrained by it.  It gets another save, because "each creature that starts its turn in the webs...must make a Dexterity saving throw."  (Its save is at disadvantage, because it is restrained).  On a failed save "the creature is restrained" - but it was already restrained by the same spell, so there is no new effect.  But what is the effect of a successful save?  Does a successful save do nothing, because spells do what they say they do, and the spell does not state what the consequences of a successful save are?  Or does a successful save count as "breaking free", so that if a creature starts its turn restrained, a successful save means it is no longer restrained?
Later in the spell, we are told that:

A creature restrained by the webs can use its action to make a Strength check against your spell save DC. If it succeeds, it is no longer restrained.

Note that a successful check here explicitly removes the restrained condition, but does not tell us that the creature "breaks free" - meaning nowhere in the spell does it explicitly describe what "breaking free" means.
Thus for a creature that starts its turn in the webs and already restrained, we are told that it must make a saving throw - but the throw does not have any explicit consequences.  We are also told that a creature remains restrained until it breaks free - but are not told what 'breaking free' means or how this can be brought about, whether by a successful check, or save, or either.
Does a successful save count as breaking free, and will it remove the restrained condition?

My answer to the question in the title would be:
No, a creature already restrained by web does not break free by making a successful save at the start of its turn.
And more closely, my answer to one of your questions in the question body:

Does a successful save do nothing, because spells do what they say they do, and the spell does not state what the consequences of a successful save are?

Yes* (but see footnote below), it does nothing if you're already restrained, this is because the same effect applied twice don't combine (BR Chapter 10: Combining Magical Effects). This still makes sense, because it's not too different than trying to shove prone someone already prone, it does nothing in effect, but it is still something that can happen.
*It does not have any direct effect, but it may still trigger other features that is based on making, saving, or failing a save. For example, on a successful save, one can react with Silvery Barbs, to give a creature advantage.

I concur. That's why at my table we skip rolling these saves for creatures that don't have any effect on roll, on success, or on failure. So most of the time. Things like Silvery Barbs might make rolling needed.

This answer would be improved by explaining what the web spell means when it says that a creature is restrained until it breaks free.  If a successful save does not accomplish this, how does one break free?

@Kirt this is already in the question, why repeating it would help? I think that repetition would be pointless.

@Mołot It is asked in the question - as a question.  I think it should be part of an answer.  At present this answer asserts that a successful check allows a target to break free, but this is not in the spell description, so I think it should be better supported by the answer.

Once you are stuck, you need an action to break free
First off, the only way the web spell restricts the freedom of its targets is by imposing the Restrained condition on them, which means they cannot move (it also slows them down, but they still can move where they want if they are not restrained, only slower, and there is no way to change that effect). Ergo, breaking free is just a less formal and more natural way of saying "ending the restraint condition". The 2014 5e rules tried to use natural language where possible, to make playing the game more intuitive and less of an exercise in rules lawyerdom. This seems like a good instance of that idea being used.
The rule for getting stuck in the webs is

Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that enters them during its turn must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is restrained as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free.

If start your turn in the webs or enter them, you have to make a save. If you fail it you get stuck, and then are restrained. Another save the following round does not change anything about that. If you are already restrained when you make it, you remain restrained (because the effect is caused by the same spell, and you either have a condition, or don't have it). If you freed yourself, or made all your prior saves, you become restrained when you fail it, or remain unrestrained if you make it. One could argue that the save is needless, if you already restrained, as it does not change anything about your situation, and so for practical purposes, you might want to skip it to speed up play.
This is different from the wording of other spells that impose conditions or effects, like for example hold person's paralyzation, which says

At the end of each of its turns, the target can make another Wisdom saving throw. On a success, the spell ends on the target.

Or slow, which says

A creature affected by this spell makes another Wisdom saving throw at the end of each of its turns. On a successful save, the effect ends for it.

Here a success ends the effect or the entire spell (and with it, the effect). Web is not saying that anything happens on a success, only that something happens if you fail.
To free yourself once you are restrained by the web, you need to spend an action and succeed on a Strength check

A creature restrained by the webs can use its action to make a Strength check against your spell save DC. If it succeeds, it is no longer restrained.

If you manage to do this, you better then also move out of the web area, or you will be stuck again when you start your next turn in case you fail the save then.

Your title says that you need an action to break free.  But the spell description says that spending an action on a successful check removes the restrained condition - it does not say that this counts as breaking free.  This answer would be improved by explaining why a successful check breaks one free, since this is not included in the spell description.

@Kirt, I added an intro paragraph to it. I think it is pretty self-evident what is meant, but maybe I am missing some kind of subtlety, entirely possible.

+1 for covering the question completely.  I think it reasonable (but not self-evident) that removing the restrained condition can be rendered in natural English as breaking free - the problem is that since the phrase is not explained by the spell, it leaves open the possibility that making the save could also count as breaking free - and hence the motivation for the question.

A successful check, at least, is 'breaking free'
'Breaking free' is not a game term - it is not even defined within the spell itself.  This means we must apply a common use English meaning to the phrase.  To break free of the spell must mean to be liberated from at least some of its effects.
If a character is restrained by the spell, a successful check removes the restrained Condition.  This likely counts as 'breaking free', because otherwise their would be a contradiction between the different parts of the spell.
The earlier part of the spell says:

On a failed save, the creature is restrained as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free.

Here, there are only two things that remove the restrained condition.
While the later part says:

A creature restrained by the webs can use its action to make a Strength check against your spell save DC. If it succeeds, it is no longer restrained.

If a successful check, removing the restrained Condition, did not count as breaking free, then this would be a third thing that removed the restrained Condition, a new thing not mentioned immediately before in the list of things that end the Condition.  It is more parsimonious that a successful check counts a 'breaking free' and thus fulfills the second of the two end conditions rather than adding a third end condition not previously mentioned.
A successful save counts as breaking free or is otherwise pointless
The spell tells us that a creature starting its turn in the webs must make a save.  But many if not most creatures starting in the webs will be there because they are already restrained.  For such creatures, a failed save results in no change of status.  If a successful save did not change their Condition either, the save itself would be pointless.  It makes more sense that the save is called for because it can actually remove the restrained Condition.
Although not explicit, it seems reasonable that either a successful check or a successful save count as "breaking free" of the webs, and certainly more reasonable than that a character is forced to make a save that has no consequences regardless of whether it is successful or not.
